# Cisco IOS code copy from tftp or scp server to device using snmp

Tags: cisco-ios, snmp

I would like to push IOS code to Cisco devices via snmp to bulk devices.
I have linux box as ftp server with ftp, scp protocol enabled. 
it would help me a lot, please tell me the procedure.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: If you have a small network it wouldn't take too long to ssh into your devices, copy from sftp and reload. I've ye to try rancid, but is very popular among network engineers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can run command on Cisco IOS using SNMP but its little complicated and not standard practice but anyway just following this document http://www.ciscozine.com/send-cisco-commands-via-snmp/

I would prefered using shell script to rancid tool to execute command on cisco devices.